# Can you have a laundry to landscape irrigation system with no sewer line?

Tags: washing-machine, laundry

I’m currently purchasing a house where they renovated over where the laundry hookups used to be, so those need to be added from scratch. A plumber looked at the house and said the best location to add the hookups was an outside location for easiest access to the sewer, but it would be very expensive and I’m  not sure about the location.

There’s a carport that’s been recently enclosed, and I think that hookups would work very well there, and rather than having the drainage go to the sewer, I could do a simple irrigation system for the many plants. Is there a problem if there’s no sewer access for the laundry?

Comment: Where are you on this planet?  Greywater systems can be quite a sticky topic, Code-wise...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I’m in Arizona. My city actually has a rebate program to encourage the installation of new greywater systems.

Comment: Ah!  That makes sense given your location

Answer (score 3):

You should reference Arizona's 13 "Golden Rules" listed in the Arizona Dept. of Environmental Quality's "Gray Water at Home" brochure. I don't think you need any special permits or permissions to use gray water in Arizona, as long as you abide by those 13 BMPs (Best Management Practices):

[Gray Water at Home](https://legacy.azdeq.gov/environ/water/permits/download/graybro.pdf)